# AWS EC2 Instance connection timed out

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have tried all the solutions but its not connecting. The solutions applied are follow.

Checked that the 22 port is already in the security group and enabled.

In the VPC-> Route table the record is already there with internet gateway.

Got 1 and 2 solutions from internet but it is already there.
Tried stop and start instance couldn't help.

it is also not connecting from the Instance->Connect->EC2 Instance Connect within AWS.

I have configured the SSL on the domain and used Route 53.

Not sure what solution I should apply now to connect. The instance was working fine and connecting when I created.

Please share your valuable feedback to solve this issue.

Comment: You say "the instance was working fine when I created" - what changed? What packages did you install? If port 22 is open in your SG, and your IP is allowed (don't add 0/0, add your IP), and the EC2 has a route to the IG, AND it has a public IP, then the issue is likely to be the instance config e.g. IPtables etc. If you're 100% locked out, you'll have to rebuild the instance.

Comment: @shearn89 I got the paid support of AWS. They told me to stop the instance and then reset the user persmissions from the Instance Settings, Edit User Data and restart the instance and it works now. They provided a script to reset the permissions.

Comment: Okay. If you want to post your comment as an answer, you can accept it and it can be upvoted!

Comment: Could you share the script that reset user permissions @AlbertScott?